# QT application app.exec() in main() code is not reached until the main window is closed

Tags: qt, static, qt4, program-entry-point, qmainwindow

I have created a QT application using QT Creator 2.4.0.
and created a main.cpp file that includes main() function as below:

```c
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(MainResources);
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    cout << "1\n";
    int retVal = app.exec();
    cout << "2\n";
    return retVal;
  }
```

When I execute this function the couts "1" and "2" are not shown at all.
I was expecting to see at least "1" in the console output.
they are printed only after I close the main window.
thus it seems as if app.exec() is not executed until the main window is closed...

1 - can anyone explain this?

When I try to execute this application from command line (the app is built statically)
the call returns immediately after I run the application.exe file, and doesn't wait for the main window to be closed.

2 - is there a way to make the application wait until the main window is closed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`app.exec()` is a blocking function (it launches Qt event loop) and doesn't return until the last window of the app is closed.

You indeed probably doesn't see "1" because of buffering issues. use `qDebug() << "1"` instead.

Comment: correct, that's why I think it is strange that when running from command line it returns, although it is blocked by app.exec() which it really is, but the command prompt decides somehow that the application is finished...

Answer (score 0):

It's highly likely that the standard output is buffered, and thus the "1" may actually be printed but isn't flushed.  You'd have to flush the standard output to get it to appear at the right time.  Or you can print to cerr instead, which is likely unbuffered.

Comment: this explains question #1
works fine after the change:

    cout << "1\n";
    flush(cout);
    int retVal = app.exec();
    cout << "2\n";
    flush(cout);

OR using cerr.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate that the program runs normally in the first case (from QtCreator?) but without the console output you expect and in the second case, running from the console directly, the program exits without showing a window? I would say that you are running two different executables.

Comment: in case I run from the console I do see the main window and I can work with the application as usual, but the command prompt returns and doesn't wait for me to close the main window!  
as if I already finished the program, I think I am missing something.

Comment: It's definitely unusual. Something is being missed because that is a typical main() for a basic Qt app.